# Simple Ground circuit layout

Tags: arduino-nano, electricity

I am making a circuit without using a PCB or perfboard and i am unsure if i am running the ground wire correctly.
[image: Grounding layout]

I usually prototype on a breadboard with the ground all joining on the far right, is this the same concept? I wanted to know if this is the accepted  convention for running the ground back to the board.

Comment: For a basic circuit like this you don't need to worry terribly about the grounding details. It's when you have higher speed and more complex signaling that it really matters.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams My final circuit is utilizing 20 pins running 2 LEDs each in parallel on a blinking program. Does that fall into the "complicated" category or is that still on the simpler side? No motors, rotors, ICs, isensors, Etc

Comment: The only problem I see is running two leds at (looking at the resistor value) 20mA each on only one pin. 40mA is the **absolute maximum** rating of a pin. 20mA is generally advised. There is also a maximum current per section of pins (see datasheet). So depending on the pattern of lights, you might run into a limit there.

Comment: Consider using a LED driver chip instead, running the LEDs in series with a higher voltage.

Comment: Further to the above point. 20pins at 40mA (ie: all lights on) is 800mA which is more than the micro can safely source.

Comment: Just because i don't understand completely, if i use an LED driver with the arduino would that solve the mA limitations and if so how?

Comment: @Mazaryk I outlined that limit yesterday at the OP's other question. I wonder if we should try to keep the whole issue in one question or rehash it over in (now) three...

Comment: Hey @Ghanima, yea this circuit keeps bringing conversations back to the inevitable question of power. All i wanted to know was if the ground wire is run correctly which they answered here. I figured if i simplified the question, i could get it answered, but i suppose I really need to rethink this circuit if it keeps raising red flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, based on basic electrical theory, you have the ground connected correctly.